How to filter objects from list based on uniqueness of object property?
I have a list of Person objects. Each Person object has an int id property, along with some others. Currently my list of Person objects has multiple objects with the same id. I want to filter the list so each id only exists at most once in the list.
E.g. a list of
Person(1),
Person(1),
Person(2),
Person(2),
Person(3),
Person(1)

should look like
Person(1),
Person(2),
Person(3)

In ruby this is simply personList.uniq { |person| person.id }
The brute force solution is to put each id in a set and check the set for every element of the list, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

You need to ensure the hashCode of Person is implemented correctly, it sounds like id is the "identity" of a Person so you might use that.
class Person {
    private int id;

    public Person(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Person) {
            return ((Person) o).id == this.id;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id;
    }
}

Now you can get a Set of Person in a few ways from a List in a few ways. For example,
List<Person> al = List.of(new Person(1), new Person(1), //
        new Person(2), new Person(2), new Person(3), //
        new Person(1));
Set<Person> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(al);
Set<Person> set2 = al.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(set);
System.out.println(set2);

Outputs
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]


Absolutely right that equals and hashCode should be implemented anyway and then that works. What about unique by any arbitrary attribute though? Perhaps something like var people = a1.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getId(), p -> p, (T, U) -> U), Map::values)); where any other getter could be used?
